# logging of different log frameworks in one file per request

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a java jaxrs web server with so many classes. Each class use a different log framework. Most of them use slf4j and some of them use org.apache.commons.logging. Also I use hadoop 1.2.0 in my program that used log4j for logging.

I want to have different log files for each request(threads that run per request) and a different log file for server.
I used MDC and siftingappender for this goal, but only slf4j log files written in thread logs. hadoop logs written in a different log file and  apache.commons.logging logs written in server log file. 
what should I do to save logs of each request in one file.

please Consider that I don't want to change all log files to log4j because of great number of classes. also I can't change hadoop logging framework because it's a jar file.

Can someone help me? 
(I apologize if my English is not good.)

Comment: What type of project you have ? Is it a webapp ?

Comment: It's a restful web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for integrating all log framework to use slf4j. I added log4j-over-slf4j.jar and jcl-over-slf4j.jar to my library. so log4j and org.apache.commons.logging use slf4j configuration for logging according to [this](http://www.slf4j.org/images/legacy.png).

But it's not sifficeint and I had a problem yet! Hadoop jobs log didn't write in its request thread log file. In fact my new problem was : "Hadoop jobs don't inherent MDC log values!". I solve it by create new logback.xml for each new request set it as new configuration file with JoranConfigurator.doConfigure().

It was my logback.xml

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

    <!-- This is MDC value -->
    <!-- We will assign a value to 'logFileName' via Java code -->
    <discriminator>
        <key>logFileName</key>
        <defaultValue>server</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>

    <sift>

      <!-- A standard RollingFileAppender, the log file is based on 'logFileName' at runtime  -->
      <appender name="FILE-${logFileName}"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${USER_HOME}/${logFileName}.log</file>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{ISO8601} %level %X{logName} : %logger{30} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

      </appender>

    </sift>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

My program copy this file and change logFileName default value to String that I want. Then set new file as configuration with this code.

```
    // assume SLF4J is bound to logback in the current environment
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    try {
      JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
      configurator.setContext(context);
      // Call context.reset() to clear any previous configuration, e.g. default 
      // configuration. For multi-step configuration, omit calling context.reset().
      context.reset(); 
      configurator.doConfigure(newPath+"/logback.xml");
    } catch (JoranException je) {
      // StatusPrinter will handle this
    }
    StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(context);
```